# How do I draw a TriangleStrip / Filling it in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, geometry, 2d

I'm trying to wrap my head around:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196409.aspx

And the reference isn't much to go on. It's short, vague and nothing that you can learn from.

I want to create a method that that takes a list of Triangle = (A class of 3 Vectors), and render it, and later be able to fill it with a color or a texture.

Can someone explain the above mentioned method? Because what I'm trying simply isn't working. I've tried adding one triangle. My understanding below, please correct me where I'm wrong.

Method when creating "One Triangle":

```
GraphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>
(
    PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip,
    "array of 3 VertexPositionColor?",
    0,
    (3? 9?),
    "I have no clue what to put here and why I should put it here?",
    "What do I put here?",
    "If 1 triangle, value should be = 1? 1 Triangle = 1 Primitive"
);
```

What do I need to make this work? Depending on how many Triangles I pass on to my methods, do I render and what values do change depending on how many Triangles there are?

...and if successful (hopefully sometime) how do I fill it?

Please, no vague short answers because the reference does that very very well.

Answer (score 6):

One clarification to your way of thinking before we begin. In XNA - you draw a wireframe (outline) triangle, or a filled triangle or a textured triangle. There isn't anything lile "draw now" and "fill later". You can only draw something else on top of what's already in the framebuffer.

Also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_mesh#Index_array) is some background on what an indexed mesh is. This is the data fed into DrawUserIndexedPrimitives (vertices and triangles composed of indices into the sett of vertices).

Given that, here's how the draw call works

```
    _effect.Texture = texture; // This sets the texture up so the 
    // shaders associated with this effect can access it

    // The color in each vertex is modulated with the texture color 
    // and linearly interpolated across vertices
    _effect.VertexColorEnabled = true;

    foreach (var pass in _effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
    {
        pass.Apply(); // This sets up the shaders and their state

        // TriangleList means that the indices are understood to be 
        // multiples of 3, where the 3 vertices pointed to are comprise
        // one triangle
        _device.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList,

        // The vertices. Note that there can be any number of vertices in here.
        // What's important is the indices array (and the vertexOffset, primitivecount, vertexCount) that determine
        // how many of the provided vertices will actually matter for this draw call
                                                      _vertices, 
        // The offset to the first vertex that the index 0 in the index array will refer to
        // This is used to render a "part" of a bigger set of vertices, perhaps shared across
        // different objects
                                                      0,
        // The number of vertices to pick starting from vertexOffset. If the index array 
        // tried to index a vertex out of this range then the draw call will fail.
                                                      _vertices.Count,
        // The indices (count = multiple of 3) that comprise separate triangle (because we said TriangleList - 
        // the rules are different depending on the primitive type)
                                                      _indices, 
        // Again, an offset inside the indices array so a part of a larger index array can be used
                                                      0,
        // Number of indices. This HAS to be a multiple of 3 because we said we're rendering
        // a list of triangles (TrangleList).
                                                      kvp.Value.Indices.Count / 3);
    }
```

I hope that is clear. Do let me know if you have any specific questions about each of the parameters and/or concepts and I can edit this post to clarify those points.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey. Thanks for answering (sorry for my late reply). My problem again with your explanation is that I'm not really use to Graphics terms and what each thing does and you pass one value "_indices" which I have no idea how to set, and the primitiveCount I still have no idea what it does. Because my lack of knowledge in the terms. I have a struct (Triangle ( A, B, C ) where A, B, C are Vector3's). How do I make a method that renders this Triangle? kvp.Value.Indices.Count ? what is that? It's too vague. Although it's a step in the right direction, because there's less errors now..

Comment: I want an explanation on how to render one single Triangle and from there create a method that renders more Triangles. So if I one have triangle (3 * Vector3), are there different number of vertices even when the value of Vectors are static? Or what am I missing?

Comment: I will post my method below, please give me some input on what I think wrong.